# Create an animated segmented control with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, web, animation, tailwind-css

I'm a primarily back-end developer, so I'm not that experienced with front end stuff. I'm using React with Tailwind CSS to create a page, and I have this segmented control on the page.

[image: segmented control]

Currently, it works just fine, and the white background and shadow statically changes between `Monthly` and `Yearly`. However, I would like to make it animated / have a transition so that the white background / shadow slides from Monthly to Yearly and vice versa. I've never done front end transitions / animations before so not really sure how to go about this, especially with Tailwind CSS.

This is the code for the segmented control currently:

```
function makeRecurrenceIntervalButtons(
  currentInterval: RecurringPriceInterval,
  setInterval: (interval: RecurringPriceInterval) => void,
) {
  return ['month', 'year'].map((interval: RecurringPriceInterval) => {
    const className = currentInterval === interval
      ? `relative w-1/2 bg-white border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 whitespace-nowrap focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:w-auto sm:px-8`
      : `ml-0.5 relative w-1/2 border border-transparent rounded-md py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 whitespace-nowrap focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:w-auto sm:px-8`;

    const title = interval === 'month' ? 'Monthly' : 'Yearly';

    return (
      <button
        key={interval}
        onClick={() => setInterval(interval)}
        type="button"
        className={className}
      >
        {title}
      </button>
    );
  });
}
```

I've looked at [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property) page extensively, but not sure how to properly apply it at all. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add [transform](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transform) class - othervise transitions wouldn't work.
Next there are a few classes to control you transition timing - [duration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-duration) and [timing function](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-timing-function)
Finally, in first case you should add translate-x-0, when it's Yearly - [translate-x-full](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate) - it should move button on it's own full width (not the parent element) in a positive x-axis direction.

So add this classes, for ex:

Monthly - `transform duration-700 ease-in-out translate-x-0`

Yearly - `transform duration-700 ease-in-out translate-x-full`